# simulation Delphi-7 MOVE function in python

Tags: python, byte, decode, encode, codepages

I want to simulate the Delphi-7 MOVE procedure by python,

```
procedure Move(const SourcePointer; var DestinationPointer; CopyCount : Integer ) ;
```

Move copies Count bytes from Source to Dest. No range checking is performed. Move compensates for overlaps between the source and destination blocks.

This is my python code :

```
def move(src, cnt):
    src_bit = "{0:b}".format(src)
    src_byte = bytes([int(src_bit[i:i + 8], 2) for i in range(0, len(src_bit), 8)])[:cnt]
    return str(src_byte[::-1], 'cp1256')
```

To do that, at first, I converted data to binary, then create byte from that bits, and finally decode binary code with cp1256 code page. this function works only for part of data and I think this problem of uncoverage of all data is because of the code page that I used. I tried to use some different code pages but not solved my problem :(

Comment: This is not a Delphi question, please remove delphi and delphi-7 tags. Just define what the move function does so that python expert can help you. Then explain what is wrong with your function that works *only for part of my data*.

Comment: I edited your question to replace your bad definition of move by the correct one for the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Move). And **you** should edit your question to better explain what usage you want. It seems related to string manipulation (Delphi Move, is a general purpose memory move function, just like C memmove() and has nothing to do with codepage).

Comment: @fpiette tnx for editing my question, as I said I try to simulate the MOVE procedure. as u know, the MOVE procedure moves a specific byte from source to destination in memory level, then converts or is better to say retrieves bytes as char value. in the Python function that I defined, I tried to simulate this transformation in memory, for doing that at first, I converted data to bit, then due to that the char type has 1-byte space in memory, I split bits into 8bits sets to create bytes and finally convert those bytes to characters.

Comment: I said that I think this problem is for the code page that I used because simulation in a bit and byte level is worked correctly but when tried to convert the byte to char run to the problem.

Comment: and I tagged Delphi in question because I thought I don't completely understand the move function and maybe the workflow that I defined for the same python function is wrong

Comment: Delphi `Move` function just move bytes around which changing any single byte. Delphi's `move` doesn't do any transformation. It has nothing to do with string nor codepage except of course it can move bytes from/to strings. I definitely have zero knowledge of python so I can't help you with that. I just want to say you are on the wrong track attracting attention from a Delphi developer. Define your python problem without any reference to Delphi since the reference you give is really incorrect and doesn't even do what you think it does.

Comment: If you want a solution, you should really explain with an example what you want to do and explain with examples what your code does when it works and when it doesn't work.